# Efficient allocation of array in r,igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to create 2 matrices with the same dimensions of the adjacency matrix of the graph i have.The problem is that the graph is way to large.
Here is my code:

```
AjM<-as_adjacency_matrix(g,attr = "weight")
dim(AjM)
```

77500 77500

```
Alpha<-array(0,dim(AjM))
```

**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 44.6 Gb** .AjM is of size 18.8Mb.
How can i do that?( i have an 64 bit machine with 12Gb ram )

Comment: Buy more memory?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `as_adjacency_matrix` has an argument `sparse`. Assuming that your matrix has fewer than 77500 * 77500 / 2 edges,  setting `sparse=TRUE` may reduce the size of the resulting adjacency matrix significantly. To use this option, you must have the `Matrix` package installed.